# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions when registering client

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this nasty error when I try to register one of my users:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions when registering client

Here is the code that facilitates my registration process:

```js
const user = await db.collection("public").doc(username).get();
    if (user.data()) {
    }
    try {
      const authUser = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );
      if (authUser) {
        await db.collection("private").doc(authUser.user.uid).set({
          username: username,
        });
        await db
          .collection("public")
          .doc(username)
          .set({
            userId: authUser.user.uid,
            profileInfo: {
              imageUrl: "",
              displayName: username,
              bio: "",
              location: "",
            },
          });

        await dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: {
            uid: authUser.uid,
            username,
          },
        });
        history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
     
    }
  };
```

And here are my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write, update, delete, create, read: if false;
    }
    match /public/{username} {
      match /{document=**} {
        allow create, write, update, delete: if request.auth != null &&
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/private/$(request.auth.uid)).data.username == username;
        allow read: if true;
    }
  }
  match /private {
      match /{uid}/{document=**} {
        allow write, update, delete, create, read: if request.auth != null &&
        request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Any idea what this particular code is causing this error?

What's weird is that when I refresh the page, I am able to access `/dashboard` and make all of my normal updates just like a logged in user should.

Comment: I actually don't think that error message is coming from the security rules, although I can't say where it *does* come from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is coming from

```
allow write, update, delete, create, read: if false;
```

Set it to true for now, and then you can edit it (maybe to only a specific uid) when your product is ready for the public.